# Why isn't my <ol> showing item numbers?

Tags: css, sass, html-lists

Alright, I don't know what's going on with this menu but when it's rendered there are no numbers to acknowledge which list item is which.

I can obviously insert the numbers manually, but that's the whole point of an ol so it'd be great if we can figure this out.

HTML:

```
<div class="go-to-menu module-dropdown" id="js-go-to-menu">
  <div class="list-head clearfix">
    <span class="item-title">Go To:</span>
    <span class="item-type">Data Level</span>
  </div>
  <ol class="go-to-menu--list">
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-bold">
      <span class="item-title">General Property Info</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Property Owner Company</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Leasing Agent Company</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Managing Agent Company</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Vendors</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Building Operation & HVAC Hours</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Property Level Custom Fields</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Projects Associated with this Property</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Activities</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Straight Line Rent Calculation (New)</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Total Expenses In This Property</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Capitalization Schedules</span>
      <span class="item-type">Property</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-bold">
      <span class="item-title">General Lease Info</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Lease Term/Options</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-bold">
      <span class="item-title">Rentable Area/Subspaces</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Base Rent</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Free Rent</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">CPI & Percentage Increases</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Operating Expenses & CAM</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Real Estate Taxes</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Utility Costs</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Parking</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Additional Costs and Credits</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Management Fee</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Occupancy/Sales Tax</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix item-green">
      <span class="item-title">Retail - % Rent</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Allocations</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Landlord TI/Tenant Contributions</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Subspace Level Custom Fields</span>
      <span class="item-type">Subspace</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Tenant's Broker</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Security Deposit</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Insurance/Asset Replacement Cost</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Sublease/Assignment Rights</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Tenant Sends Official Notices To</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Landlord Sends Official Notices To</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Holdover Costs/Restoration</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Amendments</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">LL Relocation/Audit Rights/Late Fees</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Maintenance and Repair</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Additional Clauses</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Lease Level Custom Fields</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Key Metrics</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Documents</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item clearfix">
      <span class="item-title">Email Reminders</span>
      <span class="item-type">Lease</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.go-to-menu {
    border: 1px solid $base-grey;
    display: none;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 300px;

    @media (min-height: $height-break-two) {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    @media (min-height: $height-break-three) {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    @media (min-width: $width-break-two) {
      width: 350px;
    }

    @media (min-width: $width-break-three) {
      width: 400px;
    }



    &.active {
      display: inline;
    }

    .go-to-menu--list {
      list-style: decimal;
      overflow: scroll;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .list-head {
      background: $base-grey--dark;
      color: $base-white;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 3px 6px;

      @include box-sizing(border-box);
    }

    .go-to-menu--item {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $base-grey;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 6px;
      width: 100%;

      @include box-sizing(border-box);

      &:last-child {
        border: none;
      }
     }

     .item-bold {
       font-weight: bold;
     }

     .item-green {
       color: #009600;
     }

     .item-title {
       float: left;
       width: 70%;
     }

     .item-type {
       float: left;
       text-align: right;
       width: 30%;
     }
   }
```

I can obviously insert the numbers manually, but that's the whole point of an ol so it'd be great if we can figure this out.

Comment: Seriously?  It takes all of this code to reproduce the problem?  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some left padding, the numbers should show up if the `li` displays vertically (default).

```
.go-to-menu--list {
    list-style: decimal;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 0; /* << it's this one, it needs some left padding set */
}
```

See the following simplified demo:

```css
.go-to-menu--list {
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="go-to-menu--list">
    <li class="go-to-menu--item">A</li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item">B</li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item">C</li>
</ol>
```

**EDIT**

For `li` set to `inline-block` horizontally, I suggest to use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

```css
.go-to-menu--list {
    counter-reset: number;
    padding: 0;
}
.go-to-menu--item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 6px;
}
.go-to-menu--item:before {
    counter-increment: number;
    content: counter(number) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol class="go-to-menu--list">
    <li class="go-to-menu--item">A</li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item">B</li>
    <li class="go-to-menu--item">C</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That's a no go :(

I even looked for list-style: none that might have got plugged in globally somewhere by accident and there's nothing. I'm super confused.

Comment: i Just noticed you set the li to inline-block, so you want the list item to display inline and with number before each item, right?

Comment: OK, i've updated the answer, hopefully that is what you need.

Comment: Nice that does work but still kinda glitchy. I can work with it tho. The base I'm working on doesn't really hold up to best practices as is, so I can make this work.

Thanks for the help @pangloss!